# Python 2.7 - Having trouble outputting a command line percentage bar for large file download (I want output like: 0%...25%...50%...75%...100%)?

Tags: python, algorithm, command-line, progress-bar

Apologies if this seems a basic question, I have been trying to figure out how to do this for the past hour with no progress. I have this method in Python for downloading big (10GB+) files:

```
def downloadChunks(url, destination):
    """Helper to download large files
       the file will be downloaded
       in chunks and print out how much remains
    modified slightly from: https://gist.github.com/gourneau/1430932
    """

    baseFile = os.path.basename(url)

    #move the file to a more uniq path
    os.umask(0002)
    try:
        file = os.path.join(destination,baseFile)

        req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        total_size = int(req.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip())
        downloaded = 0
        CHUNK = 256 * 10240 # 256 * 10240 == 2560 KB
        with open(file, 'wb') as fp:
            while True:
                chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
                downloaded += len(chunk)
                #print math.floor( (downloaded / total_size) * 100 ),
        if math.floor( (downloaded / total_size) * 100 ) % 100000000 ==0:
            #print "downloaded ="+str(downloaded)+" bytes"
            #print "total_size ="+str(total_size)+" bytes ("+str( (float(downloaded) / float (total_size)) )+"%)"
            #print ""

                if not chunk: break
                fp.write(chunk)

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "HTTP Error:",e.code , url
        return False
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "URL Error:",e.reason , url
        return False

    return file
```

**The problem:**

As this method runs I basically want output like so: 0%...25%...50%...75%...100% or 10%...20%... etc. (As they are big files I want the granularity to be adjustable by a constant.)

I know to use print(message,end="") but I have been having trouble with the algorithm.

**What I've tried:**

You can see some of my past experiments commented out, they gave this output, which is obviously too long for a log file.

```
downloaded =2621440 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.00428419104414%)

downloaded =5242880 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.00856838208829%)

downloaded =7864320 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0128525731324%)

downloaded =10485760 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0171367641766%)

downloaded =13107200 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0214209552207%)

downloaded =15728640 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0257051462649%)

downloaded =18350080 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.029989337309%)

downloaded =20971520 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0342735283531%)

downloaded =23592960 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0385577193973%)

downloaded =26214400 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0428419104414%)

downloaded =28835840 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0471261014856%)

downloaded =31457280 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0514102925297%)

downloaded =34078720 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.0556944835739%)

downloaded =36700160 bytes
total_size =611886812 bytes (0.059978674618%)
```

Just wondering if anyone can help me do this? Thanks very much.

**EDIT:**

I also wrote this small program, which gives incorrect output:

program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import math
scale = 100.0
CHUNK_SIZE=77   
FILE_SIZE_TOTAL =611886812
count =0.0

printnum = 25
numIncrememnts = math.floor( scale /printnum)
incrementsize = FILE_SIZE_TOTAL / numIncrememnts

output =0


while True:
        if math.floor(count) % math.floor(incrementsize) ==0:
                print str(output)+"%"
                output= output+printnum
        count = count+CHUNK_SIZE
        if count >= FILE_SIZE_TOTAL:
                break
```

output:

```
khennessy@organization-9758:~/Desktop/VM_deployer$ ./test3.py 
0%
khennessy@organization-9758:~/Desktop/VM_deployer$
```

When CHUNK_SIZE ==1 it works fine though. Here is the output for that:

```
khennessy@organization-9758:~/Desktop/VM_deployer$ ./test3.py 
0%
25%
50%
75%
khennessy@organization-9758:~/Desktop/VM_deployer$
```

**EDIT - My final answer:**

code:

```
def downloadChunks(url, destination):
    """Helper to download large files
       the file will be downloaded
       in chunks and print out how much remains
    modified slightly from: https://gist.github.com/gourneau/1430932
    """

    baseFile = os.path.basename(url)

    #move the file to a more uniq path
    os.umask(0002)
    try:
        file = os.path.join(destination,baseFile)

        req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        total_size = int(req.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip())
        downloaded = 0
        CHUNK = 256 * 10240 # 256 * 10240 == 2560 KB
    val = -1.0
    savedval=0.0
        with open(file, 'wb') as fp:
            while True:
                chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
                downloaded += len(chunk)
        savedval = val      
        val = 5 * (20 * downloaded / total_size)
        if val != savedval:
            printInfo(str(val)+"% downloaded. ("+str(downloaded)+" bytes / "+str(total_size)+" bytes)") 
                if not chunk: break
                fp.write(chunk)

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "HTTP Error:",e.code , url
        return False
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "URL Error:",e.reason , url
        return False

    return file
```

output:

```
[INFO] - 0% downloaded. (2621440 bytes / 611886812 bytes)
[INFO] - 5% downloaded. (31457280 bytes / 611886812 bytes)
[INFO] - 10% downloaded. (62914560 bytes / 611886812 bytes)
```

Thanks JuniorCompressor!

Comment: Could you try writing a little program which just prints progress?

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried that before asking, just attached it to the main answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't multiply your progress by 100 to get a percentage.

Also you can round this percentage like this:

```
print "total_size =%d bytes (%.0f%%)" % (total_size, 100. * downloaded / total_size)
```

If you want your percentages to be multiples of 25 you can use the following code:

```
print "total_size =%d bytes (%d%%)" % (total_size, 25 * (4 * downloaded / total_size))
```

`4 * downloaded / total_size` because of the integer division can have `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` as possible values, depending on which range the progress belongs (0%-25%, 25%-50%, 50%-75%, 75%-100%).

Similarly, you use `10 * (10 * downloaded / total_size)` to get multiples of 10.

Comment: A normalized progress fraction (between 0 and 1, with 1 corresponding to "complete"), multiplied by 100 indeed gives the progress percentage. So, what do you want to say with "You don't multiply your progress by 100 to get a percentage."?

Comment: The OP outputs 0.059978674618% instead of  5.9978674618% because he doesn't multiply by 100.

Comment: Funny, you described what he did not do (his mistake), and I read it like what he *should* not do. Language is difficult sometimes ;).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I am still wondering how exactly I make this only be outputted to the console every 25% or so?

Comment: Hi JuniorCompressor, thanks again but I don't think that second line works, after only a few seconds I get this line repeated over and over `total_size =611886812 bytes (0%)`

Comment: It will become 25% at 1/4 of the input.

Comment: Ah OK, but is there an easy way to make it only print when it changes, using the % operator or something? I only want it to print out five times, once at 0%, once at 25%, once at 50% etc.

Comment: You save this progress in a value, you calculate each time the new value and if they are different you print the message.